# Routes in Sails.js 0.12.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I've got a problem with the routes in Sails version 0.12.1, for the routes in file config/routes.js, for example: in version 0.11 i wrote for the views this
'/user': {
  view: 'app/user/homepage'
}
In Sails 0.11 it works, but in 0.12.1 not works, is as if Sails simply recognize app/user and not app/user/homepage.
How should i write, so that works fine?

Thanks for help me!

Comment: Are you using .ejs views?  Is there a homepage.ejs file in your `views/app/user` folder?  By "it doesn't work", what do you mean--what actually happens when you go to "/user"?

Comment: Never mind, this is a bug.  See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have discovered a bug!  I logged it [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3604) and will post an update when it's been patched and a new version of Sails is available.  In the meantime, you can work around this by setting your route thusly:

```
'/user': function(req, res){return res.view('app/user/homepage');}
```